# Front End for R helpful for novice

Tags: r

Is there any front end  that sit over R and execute codes - basically making usage of R further simpler? In my team we used to run lots of statistical things using R. There are some people who are from different background and don't have  any knowledge of statistics. For them we are planning to make some front end using R. Using which they can run the analysis by doing some simple clicks.But before doing that I thought to check with you guys if there is any readily available front end for R

Thanks in advance

Comment: Would something like Shiny suit your needs? See: http://shiny.rstudio.com/

Comment: Also see [rattle](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/rattle/rattle.pdf) it is also limited but has a convinient interface and has a desent set of options

Answer (score 6):

There is an [R commander](http://www.rcommander.com/) but using R like this is pointless and if you need a GUI-based statistical software better learn SPSS, Stata or other software. The power of R is in its abilities that are purely based on its command line interface. Using R GUI is like using a hammer instead of a screwdriver and R Commander provides you with <1% of the R features.

Better spend some time on learning R. There are lots of [websites](http://www.statmethods.net/), online courses e.g. on [Coursera](https://www.coursera.org/course/rprog) or in [other places](http://www.r-bloggers.com/in-depth-introduction-to-machine-learning-in-15-hours-of-expert-videos/) etc. It takes time but it is worth spending it.

Comment: Tim as per our company policy, we need to use some open source software for statistical analysis.So we can't able to use SPSS, Statistica.I found rattle in R but that is partially solving my problem

Comment: Available open-source GUI-based statistical software has VERY limited abilities (like R Commander): it enables you to compute linear regression, t-test, ANOVA and this kind of stuff, but not much more. However, if you want, check PSPP (http://www.gnu.org/software/pspp/) or Weka for machine learning (http://www.cs.waikato.ac.nz/ml/weka/).

Comment: Stata has been mentioned as if it were GUI-driven. But only some of Stata's facilities are available via the GUI. Almost no user-written extensions make use of it. Stata remains software for which knowing enough of the command language is essential for effective use.

Answer (score 2):

I use R Studio, I think it might be what you need.
http://www.rstudio.com/

Comment: Jon I use rstudio to code my analysis.